# Sum values with get attr and ignore "None" values in python?

Tags: python

I've got a table in my postgres db that looks something like this

```
| day_1 | day_2 | day_3 | day_4 | day_5 | day_6 | day_7 |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| 10    | NULL  | 8     | NULL  | 8     | 8     | 0     |
| 8     | 11    | 20    | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 10    |
```

and I'm trying to sum these values as such:

```
    def get_range_duration(self, start_day=1, end_day=7):
        return sum(
            getattr(self, 'day_{day}'.format(day=day), 0) 
            for day in range(1, 8) if day >= start_day and day <= end_day
        )
```

However, if a row in my table has at least one `NULL` value, I'll get an attribute error saying
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'NoneType'`

Is there a way to quickly fix it without having to re-write everything? I was thinking of something along the lines of `lambda: 0 if 'day_{day}'.format(day=day) is None else 'day_{day}'.format(day=day))` as a default value in the `getattr` method. but can't get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just adding an `or` to whatever getattr returns should do it. You'll get the value unless its either 0 or None inwhich case the `or` would return 0.

```
def get_range_duration(self, start_day=1, end_day=7):
    return sum(
        (getattr(self, 'day_{day}'.format(day=day), 0) or 0) 
        for day in range(1, 8) if day >= start_day and day <= end_day
    )
```

Comment: Would you look at that - seems to fix it. Been stuck on this for the last 2 days and a simple `or` statement seems to have solved it. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I've done that a few times too. A suggestion when you are stuck on something like this. Break it out into a `for` loop with `if` statements and then try to compress back into a generator. After the getattr you'd have an `if` for the `None` condition. That could then turn into an `x if x else 0` (but the 'or` is a bit tighter I think) that could have been squeezed back into the generator.